# "If you end your turn on this tile gain X stat." Power farming?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

So i was playing Betrayal at house on the hill, and there's several tiles that say: "If you end your turn on this tile gain X stat."

I couldn't find any rule preventing the players from just standing on that tile and ending their turn as soon as their turn begins. Is this a legal move?

I had a game where we were 4 people playing and 3 of them were just standing in the gymnasium while i was walking around finding items and such. Then i ended up being the traitor and i got madman, so my character an all my items was lost. While all of the others had max Knowledge, Speed and almost max Sanity to fight me with.

Is this legal moves? I tried reading through the Rule book but couldn't find a rule that was against this. And it's no fun being the only one exploring the house.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The FAQ/Errata, found [here](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/ah/FAQ_BHotH_102605-2.pdf), clarifies that these rooms can each only be used once per player per game.

> Chapel, Gymnasium, Larder, Library -- Can you stay in one of these rooms turn after turn to increase an attribute?
>
> > No. Each character can receive the benefit from each room just once per game (one boost for each trait for each player, if all four rooms are in play). Most players find this easy to remember, but if someone gets argumentative, keep a simple, written record.

Answer (score 2):

As someone said, that is forbidden. You can only increase your stats once, and I'm fairly sure that in more recent prints of the game (I bought my copy in May this year), the actual tiles say "once per game".